# Mysql CASE statement usage with Zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, case

I have the following query that selects some records from the database:

```
$select_person = $this->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('a' => 'tableA'), 
                array(new Zend_Db_Expr('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id'),
                        'a.cid',  
                        'a.email',
                        'final' => new Zend_Db_Expr( "concat( '<div 
                            style=\"color:#1569C7; font-weight:bold\">',
                            a.head , ' ' ,  a.tail,  '</div>')" ),
                        'a.red_flag'
                )
        )   
        ->joinLeft(array('b' => 'tableb'), ... blah blah)
        ->where('blah blah')
        ->order('a.head ASC')
```

I want to modify the above query so that it selects a different value for `'final'` depending on the value of

```
a.red_flag.
```

which can have values - true or false.

I understand I can use the CASE statement of mysql - eg something like the following:

```
'final' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE a.red_flag WHEN 'true' THEN '$concatstr1'
                        ELSE '$concatstr2' END")
```

The value of `$concatstr1 = "concat( '<div style=\"color:red; font-weight:bold\">', a.head , ' ' ,  a.tail,  '</div>')" ;`

The value of `$concatstr2 = "concat( '<div style=\"color:blue; font-weight:bold\">', a.head , ' ' ,  a.tail,  '</div>')" ;`

However, it throws an error saying

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'div 
>                         style="color:red; font-weight:bold">',
>                             a.head , ' ' , ' at line 1

How can I make this query work? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please mention your sql query. This problem is not zend freamwork. you can check your query echo $select_person; I'll can help you for write your sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the error in my statement. 
The culprit was - I was using quotes in `$concatstr1` and `$concatstr2` inside the `$select_person` statement.
The correct query should be formed as follows:

```
$select_person = $this->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(array('a' => 'tableA'), 
                array(new Zend_Db_Expr('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id'),
                        'a.cid',  
                        'a.email',
                        final' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE a.red_flag WHEN 'true' THEN $concatstr1 ELSE $concatstr2 END"),
                        'a.red_flag'
                )
        )   
        ->joinLeft(array('b' => 'tableb'), ... blah blah)
        ->where('blah blah')
        ->order('a.head ASC');
```

This is now returning me the appropriate value of '`final`' - `concatstr1` when `red_flag` is `true` otherwise it is returning me `concatstr2`.

Answer (score 3):

Personnaly, I don't like to get HTML as an answer from the DB.  It gets confusing and harder to debug and change afterwards.  Furthermore, you might get some errors due to the confusion with the ' and " and all the reserved characters in MySQL (<, >, ;, ...)  I would suggest that you try this:

```
'final' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE a.red_flag WHEN 'true' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 END")
```

Then do a check on the value of a.red_flag;

```
if($this->final) {
    $output .= '<div style=\"color:red; font-weight:bold\">';
} else {
    $output .= '<div style=\"color:blue; font-weight:bold\">';
}
$output .= $this->head.' '.$this->tail;
$output .= '</div>';
```

If the query still doesn't work.  Try

```
echo $select->__toString; exit();
```

and check the query.  Try the output that you got with the __toString on your database and check if it works.  It's easier to fix it that way.  You could also show the query string here and it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry about not being able to reply earlier. If I understood correctly, in the example that you gave, we are manipulating the result we got after running the database query. ie `$this->final` represents the value of `final` returned from the query. However, I am looking for a solution where I do not have to do this and can just get the appropriate value of `final` (based on `red_flag` value) by just running the query.