# Use MySQL Case statement in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I need to use CASE in my Zend Db Statemets, which looks like following:

```
SELECT WHERE
   CASE 
      WHEN classified_fields_values.field_id = array(5, 6, 7) THEN classified_fields_values.value >= $min_value 
      WHEN classified_fields_values.field_id = 1 THEN classified_fields_values.value = $other_value  
END .
```

Tried with query() but Zend doesn't recognize it as a function.

Below is Zend Statement, in `$select` are all necessary configurations. I know it doesn't work as it should, put there for example.

```
$select
    ->joinRight('...', null)
    ->joinLeft('...', null)
    ->where('classified_fields_values.field_id IN (?)', $_array)
    ->where('classified_fields_values.value >= ?', $min_value)
    ->where('classified_fields_values.field_id = 8')
    ->where('classified_fields_values.value = ?', $other_value)
```

Any ideas how to implement CASE in Zend Query or how to do such a query would be helpfull.

Comment: is this actually zendframework 2?? it doesn't look like. If so, you should do callback on select: $tableGateway->select(function ($select) use ($variables...){Inside here all your code, for case use \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("case...") })

Answer (score 1):

## [Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Db/Expr/Zend_Db_Expr.html)

Try:

```
'final' => new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE classified_fields_values.alias WHEN classified_fields_values.field_id = array(5, 6, 7) THEN classified_fields_values.value >= $min_value")
```

Comment: Why classified_fields_values.alias add for?

Comment: Its alias name for this case.

Comment: And how to implement it in `$select` variable? Like $select->'final'?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680451/mysql-case-statement-usage-with-zend

Comment: `$select` statement is used elsewhere also. I want to apply this case only in current `if` statement.

Comment: And is Zend_Db_Expr used for zf2 ?